# changing column type to double in mysql

Tags: mysql

is there an easy way to change column type from VARCHAR to DOUBLE in mysql table without loosing data after the comma? i tried to cast but didnt really help to convert from 1,234,567 to 1.234,567

Comment: You could find a function that removes all non-numeric characters from the `varchar` value before attempting to cast, but that doesn't address whatever conversion you're trying to do that gets you from 1,234,567 to 1.234,567 (Which isn't even a valid `double`, because it has a comma).

Comment: Does your raw data actually have commas in it? You'll need to get rid of those first with `REPLACE()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove all the commas:

```
UPDATE tableName SET colName = REPLACE(colName, ',', '');
```

Then you can change the datatype with `ALTER TABLE` and it will parse them correctly.

Also make sure that any queries that write to the column do not include commas.

Comment: thanks mate, in the end i removed the comma and i changed th column type